# How to use SerialPort On Vb6

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I have this code:

```
Dim com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
```

But when I try to type this code, it does not have the `IO...`. How may I references it in my project?

Comment: What happens when you make it `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`?

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp If I type `Ctrl` + `SpaceBar`, while you are typing it shows you possibilities of code,right ? Well, it does not recognize the `IO.`...

Answer (score 2):

That library is part of VB.NET and as such is not accessible from VB6.

The usual way to access a serial port from VB6 is the MSComm ActiveX control, although there are other COM port controls that are easier to use.

http://www.ontrak.net/visual.htm